# Can't make a ggplot with multiple lines, geom_line()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot two lines using flight data I gathered. My problem is that after trying different formulas, R is still only showing one line. I've separated my data according to regions (see image below). Can someone help me out with my formula?

If you need any additional information don't hesitate to ask, this is my first time posting on this channel.

```
ggplot(ica.vs.total, aes(x = Year, y = flights)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = region, group = region), size = 1) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image: Flight data divided by region]

[image: Result when above code is run]

Comment: The code looks ok, so presumably there is an issue with your data. It's impossible to say what this might be from a small screenshot of your data. If you make your question reproducible by including the data as text (e.g. with the output of `dput(Ica.vs.total)`) it should be very easy to help you. Without this, it's almost impossible.

Comment: Your line seems slightly darker in the plot than in the legend. Can it be that the TotalFlightsICA and TotalFlights have *identical* values, and the lines are just plotted on top of oneanother?

Comment: Do you mind telling what the solution was? Somebody else might have a similar problem and it might give them a hint at what was going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

When I enter :

```
library(ggplot2)
ica.vs.total = data.frame(flights=c(215947,197757,185782,201023,279218,261045,213343,205609),
                          region=c('TotalFlights','TotalFlights','TotalFlights','TotalFlights',
                          'TotalFlightsICA','TotalFlightsICA','TotalFlightsICA','TotalFlightsICA'),
                          Year=c(2008,2009,2010,2011,2000,2001,2002,2003))

g = ggplot(ica.vs.total, aes(x = Year, y = flights)) +
    geom_line(aes(color = region, group = region), size = 1)+
    theme_minimal()
print(g)
```

I get the expected result :

[image]

Double check your code.